# Multiple Regression analysis with more sample size dependent variable than the predictor

Tags: regression

The sample size (N) of my predictors is 35 but my the sample size of my Dependent variable (DV) is 400, what are my required so as to have all my DV sample size captured by multiple regression. thanks

Comment: Welcome to CV. I think you need to elaborate a bit more on the information you have available for your analysis and, specifically, why there is such a disparity in your sample sizes.

Answer (score 2):

If you only have 35 observations of all of your independent variables then there is nothing you can do - your sample size is 35.

However, if you have some information on the other 365 cases - that is, you have missing data on only some variables - then multiple imputation may be possible.  However, with such a lot of missing data it's going to be very tricky to get anything useful.